# Check if series of numbers is between two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to classify genomic locations, and I have DataFrame like the following, with all locations and their respective classification types. The `Type` column does not have unique classifications, but each row will have a unique combination of `Chr`, `Low`, `High`.

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'Chr':[1,1,3],
    'Low':[100,200,300],
    'High':[150,250,350],
    'Type':['Foo','Bar','Foo']
})
```

I then have my sample set that needs to be classified like the DataFrame below.

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'Chr':[1,1,5],
    'Loc':[125,325,325]
})
```

To classify the data, for each location in the sample set, the Chromosome position found within the `Chr` column must match a `Chr` value found within the reference DataFrame and the `Loc` value must be `>=` the `Low` value and `<=` the `High` value. If this happens, that row should then be labeled with the respective `Type` in the reference DataFrame. In the example I provide, the sample set should be labeled like the following.

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'Chr':[1,1,5],
    'Loc':[125,325,325],
    'Type':['Foo','None','None']
})
```

which looks like:

```
   Chr  Loc  Type
0    1  125   Foo
1    1  325  None
2    5  325  None
```

Comment: Question: Do you want each row of the second, sample dataframe compared against each row of the first, classification dataframe? In other words, if the sample dataframe has `'Loc': [225, 325, 325]`, then what should the output look like? Should it be `'Type': ['Bar', 'None', 'None']` or `'Type': ['None', 'None', 'None']`. You will get the latter from the currently accepted solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `merge` the two on "Chr". Then on the merged DataFrame, see if "Loc" falls between "Low" and "High" and use `where` to fill "Type" with NaN values if it doesn't. Finally, drop irrelevant columns and duplicate rows:

```
merged = sample.merge(df, on='Chr', how='left')
merged['Type'] = merged['Type'].where(merged['Loc'].between(merged['Low'], merged['High']))
out = merged.drop(columns=['Low','High']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Chr','Loc'])
```

Output:

```
   Chr  Loc Type
0    1  125  Foo
2    1  325  NaN
4    5  325  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `apply()` to check for each row if the conditions return a `Type` like this:

```
# Create your data frames
cat = pd.DataFrame({
    'Chr':[1,1,3],
    'Low':[100,200,300],
    'High':[150,250,350],
    'Type':['Foo','Bar','Foo']
})
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'Chr':[1,1,5],
    'Loc':[125,325,325]
})

# Check if there is type for each row
test['Type'] = test.apply(lambda x: cat[(cat['Chr']==x['Chr']) & (cat['Low'] < x['Loc']) & (cat['High'] > x['Loc'])]['Type'], axis=1)

test
```

Output:

```
    Chr Loc Type
0   1   125 Foo
1   1   325 NaN
2   5   325 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
df2 = df2.assign(Type=None)

for l in df2["Loc"]:
    i = list(df2["Loc"]).index(l)
    if df1["Low"][i] < l < df1["High"][i]:
        df2["Type"][i] = df1["Type"][i]
```

Output:

```
   Chr  Loc  Type
0    1  125   Foo
1    1  325  None
2    5  325  None
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best approach. For one you want to avoid `for` loops if possible, but the bigger issues are 1) using `index` like this will return the first occurrence of the provided value, so in this example the row with `index=2` is never checked, and 2) the code never checks the value in the `'Chr'` column to see if its a match

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on the requirements for your question, as noted in a comment on the question above. However, if the currently accepted solution that only checks the conditions you specified row-to-row, then I think this is a better solution:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Chr':[1,1,3],
    'Low':[100,200,300],
    'High':[150,250,350],
    'Type':['Foo','Bar','Foo']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Chr':[1,1,5],
    'Loc':[125,325,325]
})
mask = (df2['Chr']==df1['Chr'])&(df2['Loc']>=df1['Low'])&(df2['Loc']<=df1['High'])
df2.loc[mask, 'Type'] = df1.loc[mask, 'Type']
```

Output:

[image]

If the requirement is to check each value of `'Chr'` in the sample dataframe with ALL rows in the classification dataframe, `df1`, that match the `'Chr'` value, then this is a bit more complicated and I can update this answer accordingly, but I think @enke's solution handles this case correctly.